# I want to call the column of Account Number and Pin line by line for my Login form. This is like a username and password validity

Tags: java

I want to compare when user input - Account Number and Pin. Now, my program get the data from a .txt file and compare it. If, it matches - then gives a message "login successfully", otherwise it will display error.

This is my database:

> 0,admin,Test,123456789,123456

**This is the data in the .txt file :**

```
0 = id
admin = name
Test = lastName
123456789 = accountNumber
123456 = pin
```

and this is my code for reading the file:

```
package atm;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Login {

    public void verifyLogin(){
        String accountNumber;
        String pin;
        Scanner inputData = new Scanner(System.in);

        String fileName = "myDataBase.txt";
        try{
            File file = new File(fileName);
            Scanner readTextFile = new Scanner(file);

            System.out.println("\nAccount Number: ");
            accountNumber = inputData.nextLine();

            System.out.println("\nPIN: ");
            pin = inputData.nextLine();

            String line = null;
            while (readTextFile.hasNextLine()){
                String[] data = line.split(",");
                String dataAccountNumber = data[4];
                String dataPin = data[5];

                if (accountNumber.equals(dataAccountNumber) && pin.equals(dataPin)){
                    String name = data[2];
                    System.out.println("Welcome" + name);
                    System.out.println("\nLogin Successfully!");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Error");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And the question is..?

Comment: @Kartik how to compare when user input the Account Number and Pin then my program get the data from my data base text File and compare it if matches login successfully then if not it will display error. Can you correct my code ?

Comment: @Kartik how can i call the column of Account Number and Pin line by line for my Login form?